# what is the solution to getting error on julia pluto notebook after entering the "Struct"

Tags: julia

syntax: invalid type signature around C:\Users\admin.julia\pluto_notebooks\Revolutionary blueprint.jl#==#396279cf-6e6b-468e-8aa6-772e2279058d:1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acZEW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRwab.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a dash as part of a variable name, as it is the subtraction operator:

```
julia> x = 5
5

julia> y = 2
2

julia> x-y
3
```

So there's no way to distinguish `x minus y` from `a variable called "x-y"`. Use underscores instead:

```
julia> struct My_Struct end

julia> struct My-Struct end
ERROR: syntax: invalid type signature around REPL[47]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[47]:1
```

Comment: (a side note for Nghidengwa Jonas): The recommended naming pattern for Julia types is CamelNames so it should just be `MyStruct`.  `My_Struct` is syntactically fine but does not follow the convention.